# Java Executors : Should awaitTermination be called if we call invokeAll already

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice, executor

I recently saw some code which called executorservice awaitTermination after calling invokeAll. As I understand invokeAll is a blocking call which waits for all the tasks submitted to complete. So after invokeAll is complete we can assume all the tasks would have completed or timedout. Then my question is what would be a good reason to add awaitTermination after which also says it waits for the tasks to complete or timeout ?

Following is the code snippet

`List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(collection, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(100L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: The executor could have had other tasks submitted to it beside those provided in the `invokeAll` collection.

Comment: Those are the only tasks submitted to it.

Comment: There is no guarantee of that in the code you've given nor did you say that. `invokeAll` is simply a way to block until the executor executes the provided tasks - it makes no assumptions about the state of the executor. The `shutdown` `awaitTermination` sequence is the standard way to shutdown an executor and wait for the completion of outstanding tasks. So what you're looking at is perfectly sensible, safe Java code. It will work regardless of the initial state of the executor, or whether that state was changed from other threads.

Comment: invokeAll guarantees execution of all tasks unless timeout expires first. In both cases you do not need to awaitTermination. The latter is used for different invocation methods.